# Herencia entre clases de Java. Concesionario de coches

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, eclipse, class

Esta pregunta es bastante larga. Y la realizo porque llevo unos días intentando dar con la solución y soy incapaz. La verdad es que acabo de empezar un ciclo de programación y estoy bastante verde.

Tengo que realizar una aplicación con tres clases. Una de ellas es la clase vehículo, con unos atributos específicos, entre ellos se encuentra marca, matricula, fechaMatriculacion, precio, descripcion, nombrePropietario, dniPropietario.

Luego tenemos la clase Principal, que debe de ir en otro archivo Java, y que se encargará de ejecutar un menú principal y la aplicación en si.

Y una tercera clase denominada Concesionario en la cual debo instanciar un array de 50 vehiculos en los cuales se guardarán los datos pedidos desde la clase Principal.

Las reglas que me piden son que no puedo llamar a la clase vehiculo desde la clase Principal. Y debo de crear un método en la clase Concesionario que se llame listarVehiculos en la cual tengo que mostrar los datos almacenados en el array.

Se, o creo que se, que debo de hacer la clase Concesionario hija de Vehiculo con la palabra extends. El problema es que no se como hacer un método que me devuelva el array de todos los datos pedidos.

Además creo que no se como crear un array de objetos correctamente y que almacene los vehiculos que voy almacenando desde la clase Principal. Os voy a pasar los códigos de las tres clases.

Por favor, me gustaría que me ayudaseis porque, lo reconozco, estoy perdido. Es un ciclo online y dispongo de poca ayuda de profesores y todo lo que puedo es informarme a través de Internet.

** He tenido que eliminar la clase Principal debido a que excedía de los 30000 caracteres que Stackoverflow permite para crear una pregunta. Pero la clase Principal funciona correctamente. Lo que no se realizar el pasar los datos a la clase Concesionario. Además las reglas del ejercicio me dicen que no puedo llamar a la clase Vehiculo desde la clase Principal.

---- Clase vehículo -----

```
public class Vehiculo {                     // Clase vehículo

private String marca;                           // Variable que indica la marca del vehículo.
private String matricula;                       // Variable que indica la matrícula del vehículo.
private Double numKms;                          // Variable que indica el número de Kms.
private LocalDate fechaMatriculacion;           // Variable que indica la fecha de matriculación del vehículo. 
private String descripcion;                     // Variable que indica una descripción del vehículo. Datos adicionales.
private Double precio;                         // Variable que indica el precio del vehículo.
private String nombrePropietario;               // Variable que indica el nombre del propietario del vehículo.
private String dniPropietario;                  // Variable que indica el DNI del propietario del vehículo.

public Vehiculo () {                        // Constructor vacío.
    
}

public Vehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms, LocalDate fechaMatriculacion, String descripcion, 
        double precio, String nombrePropietario, String dniPropietario) {                  // Constructor pasando parámetros.
    
    this.marca = marca;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.numKms = numKms;
    this.fechaMatriculacion = fechaMatriculacion;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombrePropietario = nombrePropietario;
    this.dniPropietario = dniPropietario;
}

public void setMarca (String marca) {          // Método Setter para ingresar la marca del vehículo.
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getMarca() {                     // Método Getter. Devuelve la variable marca del tipo String.
    return marca;
}

public void setMatricula (String matricula) {           // Método Setter para ingresar la matrícula del vehículo.
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public String getMatricula () {                         // Método Getter. Devuelve la variable matrícula del tipo String.
    return matricula;
}

public void setNumKms (double numKms) {                 // Método Setter para ingresar los Kms del vehículo.
    this.numKms = numKms;
}

public double getNumKms () {                            // Método Getter. Devuelve la variable numKms del tipo Double.
    return numKms;
}

public void setFechaMatriculacion (LocalDate fechaMatriculacion) {             // Método Setter para ingresar la fecha de matriculación.
    this.fechaMatriculacion = fechaMatriculacion;
}

public LocalDate getFechaMatriculacion() {                                     // Método Getter. Devuelve la variable fechaMatriculacion del tipo String.
    return fechaMatriculacion;
}

public void setDescripcion (String descripcion) {           // Método Setter para ingresar una descripción del vehículo.
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getDescripcion () {                           // Método Getter. Devuelve el valor de la variable descripcion del tipo String.
    return descripcion;
}

public void setPrecio (double precio) {                     // Método Setter para ingresar el precio del vehículo.
    this.precio = precio;
}

public double getPrecio () {                                // Método Getter. Devuelve el valor de la variable precio del tipo Double.
    return precio;
}

public void setNombrePropietario (String nombrePropietario) {               // Método Setter para ingresar el nombre del propietario del vehículo.
    this.nombrePropietario = nombrePropietario;
}

public String getNombrePropietario () {                                     // Método Getter. Devuelve el valor de la variable nombrePropietario del tipo String.
    return nombrePropietario;
}

public void setDniPropietario (String dniPropietario) {                     // Método Setter para ingresar el DNI del propietario del vehículo.
    this.dniPropietario = dniPropietario;
}

public String getDniPropietario () {                                        // Método Getter. Devuelve el valor de la variable dniPropietario del tipo String.
    return dniPropietario;
}

public long get_Anios() {                            // Método Getter. Devuelve el valor de la variable anios del tipo Long. El número de años del vehículo.
    
    long antiguedad = YEARS.between(getFechaMatriculacion(), LocalDate.now());          // Variable de tipo long. La clase java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.YEARS
                                                                                        // exige que esta variable sea de tipo long. Se almacena el cálculo de años desde
                                                                                        // la fecha de matriculación hasta la fecha actual.
    return antiguedad;
}
```

}

----- Clase Concesionario -----

```
public class Concesionario extends Vehiculo {

Vehiculo[] coche;
```

//Vehiculo[] coche;                               // Instanciamos array de X objeto de la clase Vehiculo donde se
// almacenará los datos ingresados en la clase Principal.
int numeroCoches = 0;                           // Variable de tipo int para contar los coches insertados.

```
//Vehiculo coche = null;

Concesionario () {
    
    super();
    this.coche = new Vehiculo [50];
    
}

Concesionario (String marca, String matricula, double numKms, LocalDate fechaMatriculacion, String descripcion, 
        double precio, String nombrePropietario, String dniPropietario) {
    
    super(marca, matricula, numKms, fechaMatriculacion, descripcion, precio, nombrePropietario, dniPropietario);
    this.coche = new Vehiculo [50];
    
}

public void insertarVehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms, LocalDate fechaMatriculacion, String descripcion, 
        double precio, String nombrePropietario, String dniPropietario) {

    for (int i = numeroCoches; i < coche.length; i++) {
        coche[i] = new Vehiculo ();
        
        coche[i].setMarca(marca);
        coche[i].setMatricula(matricula);
        coche[i].setNumKms(numKms);
        coche[i].setFechaMatriculacion(fechaMatriculacion);
        coche[i].setDescripcion(descripcion);
        coche[i].setPrecio(precio);
        coche[i].setNombrePropietario(nombrePropietario);
        coche[i].setDniPropietario(dniPropietario);
        numeroCoches++;
    }   // FIN DE BUCLE FOR

}       // FIN DEL MÉTODO INSERTARVEHICULO.

/*public String listaVehiculos () {
    
    for (int i = numeroCoches; i < coche.length; i ++) {
        coche[i].getMarca();
        //coche[i].getMatricula();
        //coche[i].getNumKms();
        //coche[i].getFechaMatriculacion();
        //coche[i].getDescripcion();
        //coche[i].getPrecio();
        //coche[i].getNombrePropietario();
        //coche[i].getDniPropietario();

    }   // FIN DE BUCLE FOR
    return coche.getMarca();
}*/       // FIN DEL MÉTODO LISTAVEHICULOS

public int rapido () {
    int b = 3;
    double x = 2.3d;
    
    return b;
}
```

}           // FIN DE LA CLASE CONCESIONARIO

Se que el código estará mal en la clase concesionario para almacenar el array de 50 coches como máximo y el método listarVehiculo que tengo comentado no es correcto porque imagino que para devolver datos de un array habrá que usar public String [], String [], double [], LocalDate [], String [], double [], String [], String [] listaVehiculos () {}
pero no se como devolver los datos con el return de un array.

Además ese método debe ser usado desde la clase principal en el case 1 el cual tiene alguna sentencia para probar cosas pero se que no tienen sentido alguno.

No se como utilizar los arrays de objetos, ni como almacenar los datos en uno y devolverlos en returns para mostrarlos en otra clase.

Os pido ayuda y se que la pregunta es muy larga, pero no se como resumirla.

No pido que me resolváis el problema, pero que me guiéis en la solución.

Un saludo y muchísimas gracias de antemano!!!!

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo lo que te piden. Para saber si la herencia tiene sentido revisa el principio de sustitución de Liskov. En este caso parece que no tiene sentido la herencia. Creo que lo que te están pidiendo es que apliques el patrón Factory en la clase Concesionario para instanciar objetos de la clase vehículo. Aunque viendo tu ejemplo podría tratarse de implementar el patrón repositorio.

Comment: y si en lugar de mostrar todos los getter y los setter (que no aportan nada), pones un [mcve] con el codigo que realmente representa tu problema?

Comment: Me parece que debes hacer uso de un arrayList en vez de un array

Comment: *No se como utilizar los arrays de objetos, ni como almacenar los datos en uno y devolverlos en returns para mostrarlos en otra clase.* -> Lo mejor que podemos decirte aquí es que repases los ejercicios anteriores, que seguro que habéis hecho ejercicios trabajando justamente eso. En programación, al igual que en matemáticas por ejemplo, no se puede avanzar si no se tiene clara la base anterior... porque son cosas que **SIEMPRE** vas a usar (no como la tabla del 7 en matemáticas). Repasa lo anterior, haz algún otro ejercicio sencillo para trabajarlo, y luego vuelve a este.

Comment: @Dramaturgo Deberías de ser uno de los jefes de este portal. Eres un fenómeno. Era la guía que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos. La verdad que sin este portal y sin gente como vosotros me sería imposible seguir mejorando en esto de la programación.